# JSX element type 'XXX' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: typescript, jsx

I want to use material-ui in typescript.

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/react/react.d.ts"/>
import React = __React;
import * as FlatButton from "material-ui/lib/flat-button";

interface ATCProps{
    clickHandler:__React.MouseEventHandler;
}

export default class AddToCartBtn extends React.Component<ATCProps,any>{
    render(){
        return (
            <FlatButton></FlatButton>  // -> error
        )
    }
}
```

flat-button.d.ts

```
declare module "material-ui/lib/flat-button" {
    import ReactElement = __React.ReactElement;
    import Component = __React.Component;
    interface FlatButton extends __React.Component<any,any>{
    }
    export default FlatButton;
}
```

Error:(15, 14) TS2604: JSX element type 'FlatButton' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `interface FlatButton` with `class FlatButton`. The module definition you've exported doesn't have any value associated with it.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue but I cant change `interface` to `class`. Can you have a look at my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338173/typescript-how-to-import-specific-component-from-react-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

**First: please try this.**

```
import FlatButton from "material-ui/lib/flat-button";
```

**Second: why this?**

It is **default exports**.

```
// fileA: export default module
declare let $: JQuery;
export default $;
```

```
// fileB: import module from default module
import $ from "jquery";
```

if `material-ui/lib/flat-button` is 'default exports',we should use a different import form.

**Third: what happend when `import * as FlatButton from "XXX"`**

`import * as FlatButton from "XXX"` 
means import the entire module into a single variable.

```
// the outcome is an object with a default property
{
  default: FlatButton(props)
}
```

more in [modules: default exports.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, would you please consider to explain your answer?