# Typescript: How to import specific component from react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

Earlier my app was in `ReactJs + React-bootstrap`. Now I'm using `Typescript + ReactJs + React-bootstrap`

To reduce the size of the app for production Earlier I used to import react-bootstrap components using -
`import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'`

After adding Typescript it shows the following error

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./components/Hello.tsx:6:8 
>       TS1192: Module ''react-bootstrap/lib/Button'' has no default export.

`Trial 1`

`import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'` but in this case Button is undefined.

`Trial 2`

`import * as Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'` but in this case another error pops out

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./components/Hello.tsx:54:12 
>       TS2604: JSX element type 'Button' does not have any construct or call signatures.

This error shows error in line `<Button onClick={handleClick} bsStyle="danger" bsClass="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></Button>`

Though `import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'` works fine but this is not desired because it results in increasing the size of the app by 200kbs for me.

How can we import specific component from react-bootstrap using Typescript??

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I already use uglify js. But there is an increase in size when we use `import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'` as whole react-bootstrap gets imported but in {Button} the Button component gets imported. Its tried and tested that there is increase in size

Comment: Hm, I think, because of the way `react-bootstrap` is bundled, it is not possible for UglifyJS to only import everything necessary. `require` calls kill all possible optimization. If you want to keep your app size small the way @iamsaksham is doing it, is the correct way.

Comment: @SebastianSebald I haven't tested it but I think {Button} should import only the button component and not everything that what `{}` are for. If you compare a  similar approach is done with destructuring props

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri lets not deviate from the issue, importing `react-bootstrap ` for sure increases size but `react-bootstrap/lib/Button` is quite cheap in size.

Comment: Yes it only `import`s the `Button`, but it will include the whole library in the bundle anyway :( This does not happen if you import from `lib`.

Comment: Did you try to install d.ts files for all my React dependencies using `tsd install react/`

Comment: I used `@types/react`. I think after that we dont need to install d.ts!!

Answer (score 1):

Since TypeScript adheres to the ESModule spec but the `lib` is using CommonJS, you have to to the sam, you did with the React import when you switched to TypeScript.

**JS**

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'
```

**TypeScript**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'
```

Shameless self plug: I wrote about the reason for this [here](https://medium.com/@sebastiansebald/typescript-the-nitty-gritty-parts-85313547a182). I guess you will run into this issue in the future again :)

This is the version i used:

```
{
  "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.0.47",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8"
}
```

Comment: I already tried using `import * as Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'`. In this case there is another compilation error ` ERROR in [at-loader] ./components/Hello.tsx:54:12`  `TS2604: JSX element type 'Button' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Comment: Hmm. I used [this](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) to test it. Everything works "on my machine". Maybe it is an issue with the `awesome-typescript-loader`? The linked CLI uses the `ts-loader`.

Comment: From where did you use the typings for react-bootstrap? Because it says the same error for me with `ts-loader` as well

Comment: I added the `dependencies` part of bootstrap. Note that I do not have any types for `Button` if I am importing it this way :( The app works though. Could be possible that the typings are not 100% correct.

Comment: I dont know how it works for you as by using `@types/react-bootstrap` Typescript says it cant find a declaration file for `react-bootstrap/lib/Button`. I am using typings from https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap-typescript

Comment: I never used `react-bootstrap` in a project, but usually using `@types` is the correct way (if typings are not included in the module directly). I guess [these](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-bootstrap) are more up to date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141413/discussion-between-iamsaksham-and-sebastian-sebald).

Comment: Even @types/react-bootstrap have admitted that they dont have typings for individual component yet. So installing @types/react-bootstrap and importing only the component will not work at any cost. So now I'm 200% sure that your code dint work in the first place. Link to @types/react-bootstrap here - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15856

Comment: I have no reason to lie to you, I think I still have my attempt on disc, I can upload it if you want :P Regarding the typings: As I said, it did *not* have typings when importing components individually. If you change your `tsconfig` to allow implicit `any` it will work.

Comment: Man!!!! This typescript with react-bootstrap is killing me, no hard feelings brother. Can u make a plnkr or jsfiddle?? I'll make for my issue as well

Comment: Not sure if this would help you because the webpack config plays an important role, too :(